# Есть ли в .NET аналог TransactionScope для области работы с перемеными? Если нет, то реализуем ли?

Tags: .net

В `.NET` есть такая замечательная штука, как `TransactionScope`.

Пометив область `using` вся работа с БД в некоторой области будет в неявной транзакции.

А существует(если нет, то реализуемо ли) что-нибудь подобное для обычных переменных?

Скажем, в метод передаем какой-то набор объектов и важно, что бы в некоторой области выполнилось "все или ничего". Если ничего не выполнилось, то вызывающий код не увидит никаких изменений и увидя ошибку сможет попробовать сделать метод повторно не беспокоясь о том, что данные находятся в несогласованном состоянии.

Например:

```
   public bool TryDoWork(Someclass someclass)
    {
        using (var tran=new TransactionScope())
        {
            try
            {
                someclass.Field = 100500;
                someclass.Modify("123qwe");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
            tran.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Передается какой-то абстрактный класс. Соответственно, если не вызывается `Commit`, то класс-переменная не находится в несогласованном состоянии и внешнему коду не нужно заботится о том, что бы скорректировать данные перед попыткой сделать что-то повторно.

В [этой](https://habr.com/company/custis/blog/433136/) статье про что-то подобное говорится, но можно ли создать универсальное решение с учетом природы классов?

P.S Вопрос интереса ради.

Comment: добавь пример кода поясняющий на примере

Comment: @Grundy, добавил.

Comment: Я тоже таким вопросом задавался. Откаты и коммиты реализованы _внутри_ баз данных. А в простых классах ничего такого нет. Нужно самому реализовывать (или искать готовое).

Comment: [Software transactional memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory) - там есть реализации на C#. Но сам не пробовал, о качестве ничего сказать не могу. UPDATE: оказывается в статье на хабре есть ссылка на вики (русскую) с аналогичной статьей. Но в английской версии список библиотек больше.